# Grails Transparent encryption using AbstractPersistenceEventListener

Tags: hibernate, grails, encryption, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I am trying to do transparent encryption for all the domain class. Logic I am using ,I have implemented AbstractPersistenceEventListener so that I can hook into event , 
    In PreInsert event ,  I am taking all the propeties of the domain Object and encrypting as show below

```
def domainClass = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(event.entityObject.class)
def fieldsNeedtoBeEncrypted =domainClass?.constrainedProperties?.keySet()
fieldsNeedtoBeEncrypted.each {String fieldName ->
                // Getting the values of the field to encypt
                def plainText = domainObject."$fieldName"
                if(plainText)
                   domainObject."$fieldName" = Cipher.encrypt(key, plainText)
            }
```

In PreUpdate event I am trying to take the dirty properties and encrypt only those properties  ,

```
def fieldsNeedtoBeEncrypted = event.entityObject.dirtyPropertyNames
fieldsNeedtoBeEncrypted.each {String fieldName ->
                // Getting the values of the field to encypt
                def plainText = domainObject."$fieldName"
                if(plainText)
                   domainObject."$fieldName" = Cipher.encrypt(key, plainText)
            }
```

And in PostLoad event , I am trying to decrypt the data as show below ,

```
fieldsNeedtoBeEncrypted.each {String fieldName ->
            def cipherText = domainObject."$fieldName"
            if(plainText)
            domainObject."$fieldName" = Cipher.decrypt(key, cipherText)
        }
        // Don't save the decrypted value which are present in session
        domainObject.discard()
```

Problem I am facing is the data which is saved in DB during PreInsert event is not encrypted data , instead the plain text , after that PreUpdate is firing and it saves the encrypted data ,I am not not able to understand what is happening here , any body please help.

Comment: Vicky, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel   No :(

Answer (score 1):

I can offer you a workaround and an explanation of what I think the problem is.

**The Problem:**
So I did a bit of testing and it turns out that when the application persists information to the database, the events happen in the following order: SaveOrUpdateEvent, ValidationEvent, PreInsertEvent, PostInsertEvent.

As you stated, attempting to modify the entityobject when the PreInsert event is triggered will not result in the modifications being persisted to the database. I believe that the reason for this is because the information to be persisted is being collated into a separate object by GORM some time prior to the PreInsert event and that this is the information being persisted.

**The Workaround:**
Make modifications to the entityobject when the SaveOrUpdate event is triggered instead of for the PreInsert event.

Comment: It seems that entityObject is always null on SaveOrUpdate event. So the workaround won't work.